# Configur a spec file for rpm build and installation for a java project

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I was to create a RPM file for a java based project. So what I have is an Enterprise archive and some configuration file. My task is to write a spec file to build the rpm and to share so that end user can install it into the system.

At installation, the ear should be copied to the deployment folder of jboss. Database must be there if not, do create the new one.

I am able to write the rpm build configuration in spec file under %prep, %build and %install sections. However, I am not able to find how can I configure spec file so that I can copy the ear into the deployment folder and the configuration file into the required path while installation. Could you please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write "scriptlets" under Section '%pre' (processings before installation on the target host) and '%post' (after installation on the target host).

In these scripts you have to find out where your deployment folder is located.

Is your JBOSS packed in an rpm?